# Deploy GitLab repo to remote production server

Tags: git, gitlab

I have private GitLab server for development collaboration processes. I just wondering if any solution for auto deploy gitlab repository to remote production server ?

for example, i have 2 different server
192.168.1.1 for gitlab server
192.168.1.2 for production server that host my live project

the scenario is i have master repo and few branch. Master repo is the live project and branch is for development. If any commit changes to master, it automatically do sync to production server. and keep my live application up to date

i do reseach and tried few approach like this on
https://johnflynn.me/autodeploy-your-gitlab-projects/ and
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps
but both of them describe how deploying repo in the same sarver (repo and live).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to look into [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (CI) and installing a CI server (such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)) that will poll/monitor your Git repository on a particular branch and then when that branch has a new update, the CI server will auto build and deploy your application.

This also has the advantage of being highly configurable so you can perform pre-build commands and tests on the code that is to be deployed. It also means if you ever decide to move away from GitLab, you'll still have a working solution that can do auto-deployment that doesn't rely on a particular service.

---

**Behind the Scenes**

Using Git to perform auto-deployment isn't really designed for this sort of thing. Git is just a Version Control System and manages your source code.

Now this is fine if your programming in an interpreted language or scripting (Node.js, Python, etc.) because your source code ***is*** your built/compiled/deployed code.

However, for languages like C, C++, Java, C# etc, that require compiling, you'll need to build your project which Git obviously doesn't support doing as it's just a VCS.

That's where Continuous Integration comes in; To make the DQP process more streamlined and removed the need for manual deployment.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your response